# Install multiple python versions

Tags: python, pythonbrew

I would like to install several python versions to build SymPy with Sympy-bot in my fedora 18.
I came to know that `pythonbrew` can be used to do that from [here](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/05/how-to-install-and-manage-different-versions-of-python-in-linux/). I followed the installation instructions but when I try to install a python version, pythonbrew downloads the source package and start installing it. Before the completion it exits with the below error message.

> Patching Python-2.5
>   ERROR: Failed to patch `/home/thilina/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.5`.
>   127: failed to `(patch -p0 < "/home/thilina/.pythonbrew/patches/all/python25/patch-setup.py.diff") >> '/home/thilina/.pythonbrew/log/build.log' 2>&1`

Can anyone lend me a hand here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your error refers to the GNU `patch` command.

This issue probably arises from not having `patch` installed or it not being in your path.

Install this package with the following command before using pythonbrew:

```
yum install patch
```

Everything should now install correctly.